# Reading a File Containing Words in Order to Count its Frequency

Tags: java, file-io, frequency

I am working on a program that will read a file in order to find the frequency of words. I have to create a void method that will read the file of unique words to count it.

I am completely new to Java. I have been reading my textbook and other online sources in order to understand the concept/process of reading a file for this specific purpose, but I am still struggling to implement the logic of it.

I'd like to know what I am missing/or doing wrong that prevents me from reading the file to count the frequency of words.

Here is my code: [This is a part of my code. The other methods(such as the method for sorting the frequency and getting the output) are also within the same class - not included here.]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class CountingFrequencyOfWords
{
       int frequency  [] = new int [999];
       String words []  = new String [999];


       int uniqueCount = 0;
       int count_Word= 0;


       public void methodForInput() throws Exception
       {

             File file = new File("file.txt");
             Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

             String x;
             int i = 0;

             while(input.hasNext())
             {

                   x = input.next();
                   count_Word[i] = x;
                   i =  i + 1;


                   if (i == uniqueCount)
                   {

                         uniqueCount[i] = x;
                         uniqueCount = uniqueCount + 1;
                   }

                   frequency[i] = frequency[i] + 1;

             }


        }

}
```

Comment: Charlotte, do you have a specific question?  What is it that you actually want people to post, in response to this?

Comment: @DavidWallace, I want to know  how I can get this method to read a file in order to count the words within the existing file.

Comment: OK, but you say you've already written some methods that you haven't shown us.  I'm not sure which bit you're missing.  In any case, I would suggest you create a `HashMap<String,Integer>`, keyed by the words that you find, and increment the `Integer` every time you see a word.  Is that the part that you don't know how to do?

Comment: @DavidWallace, yeah...but I have to use two arrays for this specific program.

Comment: @Charlotte.P Create a String array, and an integer array.  The string array holds all unique words you've encountered.  The integer array holds each word's frequency.  For each word in file, find the word in your string array, and increment the corresponding index in your integer array.  if the word doesn't exist, add it to your string array.

Comment: hi...@Charlotte.P do you have problem only in reading file and not in shorting or counting frequency of words etc...???

Comment: @Ankit, I am having problem to get the void method to read the file to count the frequency of words.

Comment: Your code for actually reading the file is correct.  What is going wrong for you?

Comment: Oh now i see.....first tell me where you are calling your methodforInput().....there you are using try & catch blocks or not??

Comment: @DavidWallace, the error message that I am getting so far is "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int" for:  "count_Word[i] = x;"    and     "uniqueCount[i] = x;"

Comment: Right.  Your arrays are `words` and `frequency`.  So you probably wanted the first one to say `words[i]=x;` instead of `count_Word`.  You still don't have code for working out the frequency.

Comment: @Ankit, I am calling this method from  the main method. I have the methodForInput() static as well the four first variables at the beginning of the code. I am not using try&catch blocks. Is it really necessary in this case?

Comment: As an aside, if you have a few compile errors, it would be good if you included them in the question, so that we don't have to find them all for ourselves.  This will get you a faster response.

Answer (score 0):

Well I cant tell you now that count_Word and uniqueCount are not arrays so count_word[i] and uniqueCount[i] will screw you up. And x is a String so adding it to the int variables you'll get exceptions thrown. other than that i think your reading the file is fine.

Answer (score 0):

it...is very very very necessary to use try & catch block for your `methodForInput()` function because in the declaration of your `methodForInput()` function you have thrown an Exception `public void methodForInput() throws Exception` ...so now you have to catch this exception where you call your function if it is thrown during the execution of program......here is the block of code:

```
try{   //try it for exception
    methodForInput();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e); //print the exception if it is thrown during execution of program
}
```

don't worry if exception is not thrown...if no exception occur then code run without any problem if exception occur then it will be displayed by `System.out.println(e);`........I think it may help you..& don't forget to make `methodForInput()` method as `static`.....good luck...